# Verifying a structure of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Does this sentence sound awkward?

> This is one of the main reasons of focusing on *X* during my master’s
>   studies, among many, such as *X* could have a high ITR comparing to
>   other techniques, and (*X*) letting users focus on the task more
>   conveniently.

Can it be improved to sound more professional?

Comment: **This** points at something already said.  You should include the previous sentence.  If you are not referring back to something, then **This is ...** is the wrong way to begin the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `among many` seems unnecessary given that you have already stated that there are a plurality of reasons and that what you are describing is one of them; but if you wish to retain it, I would place it at the start of the sentence, amongst other minor grammatical changes:

> This, among many, is one of the main reasons <s>of</s> **for** focusing on *X* during my master’s studies, <s>such</s> as *X* could have a high ITR when compar**ed** to other techniques, <s>letting</s> (allowing/enabling?) users **to** focus on the task more conveniently.

Though, `conveniently` sounds unnatural in this context, as I'm unsure how one could focus one something more *conveniently*.

> allowing users to better focus on the task.